# libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - even when using open cv headless

Tags: python, docker, opencv, aws-lambda

I have a Docker image I am building to run on AWS Lambda.

One of the dependencies is opencv, but I am using the headless version.

My requirements file is:

```
absl-py==1.0.0
attrs==21.4.0
cycler==0.11.0
flatbuffers==2.0
fonttools==4.33.3
imageio==2.19.2
jmespath==1.0.0
kiwisolver==1.4.2
matplotlib==3.5.2
mediapipe==0.8.10
networkx==2.8.1
numpy==1.22.3
onnxruntime==1.11.1
opencv-contrib-python-headless==4.5.5.64
packaging==21.3
Pillow==9.1.1
protobuf==3.20.1
pyparsing==3.0.9
python-dateutil==2.8.2
PyWavelets==1.3.0
scikit-image==0.19.2
scipy==1.8.1
six==1.16.0
tifffile==2022.5.4
urllib3==1.26.9
```

And my Dockerfile is:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt && rm requirements.txt

COPY lambda_function.py ./
COPY remove.py ./
COPY detect.py ./
COPY u2net.onnx ./
CMD [ "lambda_function.lambda_handler" ]
```

The exact error I am getting in Lambda is:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

I have tried researching what could be happening but have come up empty handed.
Why would I be getting this error when using the headless version?
Thank you

Comment: probabily also the opencv contrib module should be headless: "opencv-contrib-python-headless"

Comment: please ONLY use `opencv-contrib-python-headless`, not both

Comment: @berak just to clarify, are you saying to get rid of `opencv-python-headless` and just have `opencv-contrib-python-headless` as the opencv install?

Comment: yes, exactly !!! (it already contains opencv-python)

Comment: @berak I have updated my question with the requirements I am using now. I have tried it with the new list and it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: "I have updated my question with the requirements I am using now. " -- maybe better leave the old ones there, commented out, with an "edit" note ? hard to reason, what this question was about originally, else. also, how do we know exactly, that this IS related to the opencv module ? afaik, even the "gui-enabled" pypi builds do not use opengl

Comment: changing the requirements.txt doesn't help if the conflicting packages are already installed. start with a clean container/VM or make sure to remove those packages. **AND** make sure none of these dependencies (and theirs...) force installation of a conflicting OpenCV package variant! that's a common issue with easyocr, to name just one. apparently python/pip does not allow declaration of a "depend on *any of* these packages"

Answer (score 8):

I needed to update my container repositories and install a dependency, `libgl1-mesa-glx`:

```
RUN apt update
# Dependency for opencv-python (cv2). `import cv2` raises ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
# Solution from https://askubuntu.com/a/1015744
RUN apt install -y libgl1-mesa-glx
```

Comment: I'm hoping these work on amazonlinux:2018.03